# RegEx Matching Characters That Don't Have Specified Space

Tags: python, regex

My RegEx can also be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/iHWG8g/2/), although I manually inserted characters to look for carriage returns.

```
((?:\d{6}?)([A-Z\d]{3})?(?:[\^r\ ]+)(([A-Z\d]{6}|[A-Z\d]{5} |[A-Z\d]{4}  ))?)
```

I've specified a blank space after a 5 and 4 character string, but yet my regular expression seems to be ignoring it at least on the first line. It matches "EXTEND" even though I don't want it to. Only if there's a space after. It works on the third line though with "XOBUS ".

```
FPCN54 CWNT 080810^r^r EXTENDED FORE    #should not match anything
ASUS42 KMHX 080425^r^r RWRMHX^r^r WEAT  #should match RWRMHX
RXUS30 KWNO 081300^r^r XOBUS ^r^r GREA  #should match XOBUS w/ 1 trailing space
FXUS64 KEWX 081112 RR3^r^r AFDEWX^r^r   #should match RR3 and AFDEWX
```

Edit: Forgot to include a 3 character alphanumeric before the first carriage return. See line 4. Need to capture that as well.

Comment: It is better to explicitly say what is the idea of your regex (it should match 4th word that is followed by ^r^r or something like this, yes?). Because regexes are not so easy for possible answerers to parse (especially if you have any mistake in it).

Comment: @Sanyash After a 6-digit string, it should match either a 6 character alpha-numeric string, a 5 char alpha-numeric with a space, or a 4 char alphanumeric with two space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your desired output above, you're overcomplicating the regex.
**BTW, above you said, '5 or 4 character string,' but in your desired output, you have a "6" character string and a 3 character string.**

```
>>> import re



>>> string = '''FPCN54 CWNT 080810^r^r EXTENDED FORE    #should not match 
anything
ASUS42 KMHX 080425^r^r RWRMHX^r^r WEAT  #should match RWRMHX
RXUS30 KWNO 081300^r^r XOBUS ^r^r GREA  #should match XOBUS w/ 1 trailing 
space
FXUS64 KEWX 081112 RR3^r^r RR3555^r^r AFDEWX^r^r   #should match RR3, RR3555, and AFDEWX'''



>>> re.findall('(?m)([\d]*[A-Z]+(?:[A-Z]*[\d]*)*[\s]*)[\^r]{2,}', string)



#OUTPUT
['RWRMHX', 'XOBUS ', 'RR3', 'AFDEWX', 'RR3555']
```

Comment: I forgot that I also need to match a 3 character alpha-numeric, if included, after the 6-digit string. See edit.

Comment: @klex52s Additionally, I assume they must begin with letters? Capital Letters?

Comment: Actually, there are a few instances in which it may start with a digit!

Comment: Yes, only capital letters.

Comment: @klex52s I edited the string and made a new regex. The ranges that you're posting about are kind of inconsistent though. You can play around with the above.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/McMc3h/1) might help you to perform an exact match and divide your string inputs to several groups, if/as you wish, and reconstruct your target outputs:

```
([A-Z0-9]{6})\s([A-Z]{4})\s([0-9]{6})([\^|r])+\s([A-Z]+)([\^|r\s]+)(.+)
```

You might remove any group `()` that you wish and it would still match.

[image: RegEx]

You can reduce boundaries, if you wish.